# Lambda vs Query Expression Entity framework / Foreign Key relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In brief: is there any difference between fetching records using lambda expression vs using query expression?

In below example:

1. I fetched one employee record
2. Modified his salary Without saving
3. changes to context I fetch same record with Salary table included

Why are the results different when doing query 2 vs query 3?

```
var empdId = Guid.Parse("C8475622-09A9-4284-80D4-AAXXK");
//City for this employee was Washington in database
var emp = ctx.Employee
    .FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.ID == empId);
emp.City = "New York"; //Modified the entity

//Lambda version
//Fetched again including foreign key relation Salary
var employeeCity = ctx.Employee.Include("Salary")
    .FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.ID == empdId).City;
//New York

var cityfetchedAgain = from e in ctx.Employee
                    join sal in ctx.Salary on e.ID equals sal.EmployeeId
                    where e.ID == empdId
                    select e.City;
var city = cityfetchedAgain.FirstOrDefault(); 
//Washington
```

**EDIT:**
I will re-phrase my question: `Include` version of query returns the changed property, even if the changes are not committed to database. However `LINQ Join` is not aware of changes in the context (City property here). Records were fetched from database.

> I have explicit foreign key configured between these tables. Should I
>   always prefer Include?

Comment: `include` and `join` are not the same.

Comment: The 2 queries in your example are not the same, but not because one uses query syntax and the other uses extension methods, but because they are not the same.

Comment: In your 3rd query return the status field and 2rd queries return city. So both fields are same?

Comment: @PragneshKhalas 3rd query was a typo fixed it.

Comment: The queries are different, and since neither of them has an explicit **ordering**, the `.FirstOrDefault()` (which basically translates into a `TOP (1) ....` ) can select whatever row it feels like as the "first" row from the result set .....

Comment: Is `devId` the same as `empId`?

Comment: @acfrancis typo fixed

Comment: I think @marc_s is right. If that doesn't explain it, the different results might be caused by some other simple error in your code. For example, I'm not trying to nitpick but what is `d` in `select d.City`?